# All columns values in one column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-custom-function

I need some help! :S
I have a spreadsheet and three list of items (Column "A", "B" and "C") and I need to put all the values of all the columns in only one column (Column "E"). A picture is following here... I tried everything I could but the true is that I'm not an expert in sheets. So if you can help me to simplify this with a fonction or formula or a miracle :S lol... it would be really appreciated. I really Hope you can help me.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use in column `E` the `Flatten()` function, like this:

```
=flatten(A2:A30,B2:B30,C2:C30)
```

**EDIT**

try this other:

```
=query(flatten(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C),"where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: It works... but... my A column have 37 rows, the B 36 and C have 285. So I put the rights rows in the formula and it work but the columns A B and C change constanly... I goes with =FLATTEN(A2:C) but the results have blanks cells between values... do you know how can i make the formula counts only the values of the columns and ignores the blanks ones?

Comment: there is a new formula for you :)

Comment: THANKS A LOT! it works VERY WELL!!!!!